# WCF Protocol Exception

Tags: wcf, exception, performance

We are getting some weird behavior from a service we have deployed on a remote system which we are using to access and post data to.

Retrieving information from the service doesn't seem to be an issue. However, whenever we try to execute insert methods on the service we get an `System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException`. The weird thing is, it will successfully execute approximate 40 records before faulting.

The client is communicating over SSL and TransportWithMessageSecurity is enabled on the wsHttpBinding.

The error message is being generated at the "Set up Secure Session activity":

> System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException,
>   System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>
> The content type text/html of the
>   response message does not match the
>   content type of the binding
>   (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8).
>   If using a custom encoder, be sure
>   that the IsContentTypeSupported method
>   is implemented properly.

We have tried a number of tests all of which consistently fault as soon as we reach a particular number of inserts.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this. I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I'm having this problem as well. I can call my service hundreds of times successfully, and then I get ProtocolException all of a sudden.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if the [trace viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751795.aspx) might shed some light here? No idea what the problem is, I'm afraid...

Comment: Hi Marc, the trace viewer is what gave me the exception in the first place. I can recreate the error  and get the same result, but I don't know what is causing it.

Comment: then I'm stumped; if it didn't work at *all*, there are a number of ideas - but stopping after a short while? Odd.

Comment: Further testing has revealed that there may actually be a configuration issue with the SSL certificate on the host. Might be a few days before I know more but will post solution if I ever find out what the issue was. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If a piece of code sends you HTML, then you should probably read it to see what it says.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have reached the configured message size and the WCF infrastructure is truncating the SOAP message, making the serializer (Contract or XML Serializer) to not be able to deserialize the message.

Try increasing the WCF request size see [< readerQuotas >](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731325.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET might not be configured properly for .NET 4.0
navigate where .NET 4.0 is installed and try running the following command to reinstall it:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis.exe -iru
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help somebody. My problem was: I have a web site consuming a WCF service.
After deploying the web site, I forgot to deploy the WCF service, too.

After deploying the WCF service, all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I  ran  into  the  same  problem.  Finally, I got a solution by adding some  code in the `web.config` file.

I added these  under the `<basicHttpBinding>` tag:

```
<binding  name="xyz">
  <security mode= "Transport" />
</binding>
```

Comment: Hi,

I ran into the same problem. Finally I got a solution by adding some codes in the web.config file.

Added these under the <basicHttpBinding> tag

 <binding name="xyz">
   <security mode="Transport" />
 </binding>

Hope this will help